# Multiple lists with multiple options

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to create 3 different lists with the first containing different car brands, the second the model of the car and the third the motor of the car.

Once the user has selected the first option, which is the car brand he should then get the options for that car in the next drop-down list and from that option the third drop-down list should adjust to that specific model.

If my explanation was too hard to understand here's an example of the exact thing I'm trying to create. http://www.quantumtuning.se/?page_id=36

Would appriciate if someone could hand me a link to a guide or explanation somewhere because I've been looking everywhere without success.

Comment: There's many libraries out there that makes this sort of thing easy, angularjs, reactjs, to name a couple. To use just vanilla javascript. You are going to need to learn how to bind events tied to the dropdowns and change the subsequent dropdowns. Google `addeventlistener` for starters.

Comment: How you develop the solution will also depend on how you retrieve the option data. Is it just one massive nested multi-dimensional array, or will you have to use Ajax to retrieve the next sub-list when a selection is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as KJ said - also, you could use jQuery change() eventlistener to see when the value changes, and the repopulate another select box:

```
<select id="make">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select
```

>

JS:

```
$('#make').change(function(e){

    switch($(this).val()){
      case 'volvo':
          //code to populate model list
      break;
      case 'saab':
          //code to populate model list
      break;
      //etc...
    }
});
```

Comment: obviously - you could hook this up to a relational array or data object to select the correct attributes...

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure it out from there.